# Ubuntu 12.04 hangs during boot, failed at "Starting NetBIOS name server"

Tags: 12.04, samba

I have newly installed ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS on a Macbook Pro '13, everything works fine but after I shared a folder and installed samba and some other features which the system prompt me to install when I share the folder, I can't boot the system anymore. It hangs on here:

[image: Screenshot]

I can get network working in recovery mode and I removed samba in recovery mode but it doesn't help.

What can I do now? I really don't what to reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: Can you edit the grub line and remove the `quiet`? I'm pretty sure samba won't block the boot sequence.

Comment: I solved this by remove and re-install gdm in recovery mode.
First time I used root to install gdm, but still can't boot, then I switched to my own user and install gdm with sudo in recovery mode, after reboot everything goes fine!

Comment: You can add the exact procedure as answer above, please :).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by remove and re-install gdm in recovery mode. 
First time I used root to install gdm, but still can't boot, then I went to recovery mode again as root and then switched to my own user and install gdm with sudo, after reboot everything goes fine!